# Delete Registry keys while installing msi using custom actions

Tags: windows-installer, registry, key

I am trying to delete some file associations key in registry for our previous product so that when our new product is installed using MSI it prevents conflicts and opens the correct product.

My problem is when i try to add an `.exe` using custom action in the MSI install process, it is not able to get the correct registry key (probably because of security reasons because the trace message doesn't get all the `subkeys` in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\` folder).

I wanted to know if there is any other way to delete keys from registry during `MSI` installation using custom actions.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in Advance  .

Comment: What MSI authoring tool do you use?

Comment: i am using vs 2008 deployment project to build MSI.

Comment: I have no experience with VS setup project. Will [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdh2ws5k.aspx "How to: Add and Delete Registry Keys in the Registry Editor") help you?

Comment: Well i guess thats for the keys that are being added by your current project but our problem is we want to remove keys that were added by our previous project.Please correct me if i am wrong because i am amateur in whole MSI installation process.

Comment: Yes, VS seems to support only this way, or `Registry` table. You can use a JScript to add `RemoveRegistry` table into your package after MSI is created in VS.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't use custom actions to do things which Windows Installer can handle.*

Instead of using custom action to delete a registry key, add a row into [RemoveRegistry Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371208.aspx), and set `Name` column to `-`.

The steps to do it are different for each MSI authoring tool.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for your prompt response. i read through the link that you provided and it says that key gets deleted only if the component is uninstalled and we are not uninstalling the previous product from clients machine but removing the file associations so that when users open files it will open in our new product and not the older version. the Previous version is a ClickOnce version whereas the new version is MSI.

Comment: Yep, you're right. You need `RemoveRegistry` table instead of `Registry` table. I have edited my answer accordingly. Yet, from looking the the documentation on [Properties for Registry Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbxyfa24.aspx), it seems this is not supported in Visual Studio Setup Project.